# Python Multithreading Pool Windows Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, threadpool, python-multithreading

```
import multiprocessing as mp    

    with mp.Pool(3) as pool:
        res = pool.starmap(sim.cosine, ((std_matrix[i], std_matrix[j]) for i in range(nU) for j in range(nU)))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    cos_matrix_uu = np.array(res).reshape(nU, nU)
```

In the Above code `nU = 6040`, so in total I loop `36.481.600 (6040 * 6040)`.

I have my values in a 2d array `std_matrix` of size (6040, 3060).

foreach each pair of rows in `std_matrix` I calculate the cosine similarity:

```
def cosine(a, b):
    """Calculates the Cosine Similarity.
        :param a: array of ratings
        :param b: array of ratings
        :return: Cosine Similarity
    """
    divisor = (np.sqrt(np.dot(a, a)) * np.sqrt(np.dot(b, b)))
    if divisor == 0:
        return 0
    return np.divide(np.dot(a, b), divisor)
```

When I run this code without multithreading it executes, but with multithreading my pc freezes. Even when I use 3 threads.

My gpu is a GTX850M. Anything I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your task is a cpu-intensive task, not IO-intensive task. python's multithreading can not distribute to multi core because of the python's GIL. so at a moment, there will be only one thread could run. It is not suitable with this task type.
Just use multiprocess.

Comment: What do you mean with &quot;just use multiprocess&quot;? I also used ThreadPoolExecutor before, but same happened with that. Isn't what I'm using now multiprocess?

Comment: Yes, you are using multiprocess. What I mean is do not include the multithreading . just use multiprocese only.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question:
Let&#39;s say I have a large 2d array of floats. (5k,5k) size (= 25 mil values). I want to compute a function with every float in the array and reassign it in the same position. How do I multithread this such that python doesn&#39;t freeze up? Is this possible?

Comment: already said, it is not suitable with this problem. But it can do it definitely.